# I have to print a grid with a space after every 3 elements in a row and a blank line after every three row, but I could not figure out the code

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have a 2D array of columns as = `[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]` and I have to print it out like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kbfd.png)

```
    for n in range(9):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i] , ' ', end = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the nested arrays are all the same length you can do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(str)
your_array = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]

for n in range(len(your_array[0])):
  for i in range(len(your_array)):
   result[n] += ' ' if i%3 == 0 else ''
   result[n] += str(your_array[i][n])

for line, j in result.items():
  if line % 3 == 0:
    print('')
  print(j)
```

output:

```
 123 456 789
 123 456 789
 123 456 789

 123 456 789
 123 456 789
 123 456 789

 123 456 789
 123 456 789
 123 456 789
```

**UPDATE FROM COMMENT**

defaultdict is just a convenience class here so it's fully optional. The same code without defaultdict would look like:

```
result = {}
your_array = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]

for n in range(len(your_array[0])):
  for i in range(len(your_array)):
   if n not in result:
     result[n] = ''
   result[n] += ' ' if i%3 == 0 else ''
   result[n] += str(your_array[i][n])

for line, j in result.items():
  if line % 3 == 0:
    print('')
  print(j)
```

Also the if you wanted to use zip as suggested below your code would simplify to:

```
your_array = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]

your_array = zip(*your_array)
for idx, sub_array in enumerate(your_array):
  result_str = ''
  for sub_idx, value in enumerate(sub_array):
   result_str += ' ' if sub_idx%3 == 0 else ''
   result_str += str(value)
  if idx % 3 == 0:
    print('')
  print(result_str)
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve it without importing  defaultdict?

Comment: See above, I added code not using defaultdict and also a shorter alternative using zip

Answer (score 0):

One way using `str.format` and `enumerate`:

```
fmt = "{}{}{} {}{}{} {}{}{}"
for n, g in enumerate(zip(*grid), 1):
    print(fmt.format(*g))
    if not n % 3:
        print("")
```

Output:

```
123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 789

123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 789

123 456 789
123 456 789
123 456 789
```